# How can you get Gradle to fail the build when there's a non-UTF8 character in the source code?

Tags: gradle, javac

It's a rare enough problem, but I'd really like for it to fail the build when this happens:

```
/Users/jundai/perforce/trunk/service/test/com/mycompany/PriceFormattingTests.java:93: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
       return new CurrencyModel("373959", new Price("10.20", "EUR"), "�10.20", new Price("12.10", "USD"), "$12.10");
```

With Ant or running `javac` on the command-line, using `-source 1.6` or `-source 1.7` will cause this to fail.  Using Gradle, it prints out as an `error:` (if `sourceCompatibility` is set to 6 or higher), but the build is still successful.

I've tried various ways of getting the `-source` argument into the `javac` command for the `compileJava` task, but nothing I've tried seems to be able to get Gradle to report this as a failure.

Has anyone else run into this?

EDIT: some more details:

If I have a file encoded in `winansi`: `src/main/java/Test.java`:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Testing UTF-8 compilation: C’est drôle, tout à coup je ne sais pas quoi dire.");
  }
}
```

then this passes with no errors or warnings using this `build.gradle`, Gradle 1.3, and Java 1.7:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

tasks.withType(Compile) {
  options.encoding = "iso-8859-1"
}
```

Output is:

```
[1.9.3-p327] gradle$ gradle build
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test
:check
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

If I remove the `options.encoding`, or set it to `UTF-8`, I get this:

```
[1.9.3-p327] gradle$ gradle build
:compileJava
/Users/jbateskobashigawa/play/gradle/src/main/java/Test.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
    System.out.println("Testing UTF-8 compilation: C�est dr�le, tout � coup je ne sais pas quoi dire.");
                                                    ^
/Users/jbateskobashigawa/play/gradle/src/main/java/Test.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
    System.out.println("Testing UTF-8 compilation: C�est dr�le, tout � coup je ne sais pas quoi dire.");
                                                           ^
/Users/jbateskobashigawa/play/gradle/src/main/java/Test.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
    System.out.println("Testing UTF-8 compilation: C�est dr�le, tout � coup je ne sais pas quoi dire.");
                                                                     ^
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
... (more stuff)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Setting the `sourceTypeCompatibility` between `1.5`, `1.6`, and `1.7` doesn't seem to do much.  `1.5`, when using `-source` on `javac` turns the error into a `warning:`.  With Gradle, it's still an `error:`, but interestingly it doesn't get recompiled on the next build, whereas with `1.6` and `1.7` it does.

I've tried all sorts of ways to try to pass `-source` into javac when Gradle is building, but none of them seem to work:

Doesn't build:

```
    options.compilerArgs < '-source 1.7'
```

Builds, but doesn't error out (same as without the flag):

```
    options.compilerArgs << '-source'
    options.compilerArgs << '1.7'
```

All of this seems to have something to do with the fact that Gradle isn't actually using the `javac` executable to compile—it's using some sort of JVM compile API that has a lot of very convoluted code in it.  If I try to replicate what Gradle *seems* to be doing, I can create a class to compile my class that looks like this: `javax/tools/CompileTest.java`

You can reproduce the problem using this mini project: https://github.com/Jun-Dai/gradle_utf8_compilation_issue

Does anyone know of a way around this problem, short of parsing the Gradle build output and failing the build based on that particular error message?

Comment: Sadly not. Periodically I look at the build output and if I see the above warning, I manually fix it. I guess this problem is rare enough that that's actually a workable solution even on a large codebase with lots of developers.

Comment: I solved my problem simply using android { compileOptions.encoding = "Cp1252"

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this will allow it to fail the build:

```
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
```

Not sure if that has other ramifications, however, but I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

```
//ignoreFailures = true
```

Insert and Uncomment the above line if you want it to fail, put this statement under the following section, see if it works.

```
tasks.withType(Compile) {
     options.debug = true
     options.compilerArgs = ["-g"]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **buildscript { }** section of build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
```

**UPDATE**
You can now do this:

```
android {
  compileOptions.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Comment: You must put that block inside the buildscript { } block at the top of your build.gradle.  Did you do that??

Comment: I don't have a `buildscript {}` block at the top of my build.gradle, but when I tried adding one just now, the result is the same.  Here's the build.gradle for my example: `apply plugin: 'java'`

`buildscript {
    tasks.withType(Compile) {
      options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }
}`

Comment: See my edited answer, and try to make your build.gradle like that.  Also, you may also want to run gradle clean first...

Comment: After downloading lombok and a ton of other fun stuff, it still behaves the same when doing a clean build: it prints out the errors but continues on as a successful build.  :-/